# Android listener always null when attach in a DialogFragment

Tags: android

high school teachers here trying to teach how to implement a DialogFragment with listener attach with an interface to the fragment that show it. for some reason the listener is always null and while the dialog show, when I press the ok or Cancel button of the Dialog, the transfert to the implement method dont work, it stop a the line where I call the listener class (always null) in the alertDialog.Builder Here my code, thank

here my Fragment that call the dialogfragment

```
    package net.ccl.monapp.ui;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import net.ccl.monapp.R;


public class AnimationFragment extends Fragment implements MonDialogFragment.MonDialogListener {


    public AnimationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_animation,container,false);
        Button myButton = root.findViewById(R.id.bt_dialog);
        final TextView tvTitre = root.findViewById(R.id.tv_titre);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DialogFragment myDialog = new MonDialogFragment();

                // Show Alert DialogFragment
                myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
            }
        });

        return root;
    }





    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        TextView myTitre = getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_titre);
        myTitre.setText("Mon nouveau titre");
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Vous avez canceler l'action du dialog",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

here my DialogFragment

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;




public class MonDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public MonDialogFragment() {

    }

    public interface MonDialogListener {
        void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
        void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    }

    // Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
    public MonDialogListener listener;



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
            listener = (MonDialogListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        AlertDialog.Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle("Mon interface dialog");

        builder.setMessage("Ceci est un message qui explique que tu peux changer le titre du fragment animation en cliquant sur ok");

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        listener.onDialogPositiveClick(MonDialogFragment.this);

                    }
                });

        builder .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        listener.onDialogNegativeClick(MonDialogFragment.this);
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }


}
```

and here my logcat

```
 Process: net.ccl.monapp, PID: 13691
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void net.ccl.monapp.ui.MonDialogFragment$MonDialogListener.onDialogPositiveClick(androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment)' on a null object reference
    at net.ccl.monapp.ui.MonDialogFragment$1.onClick(MonDialogFragment.java:56)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onAttach()` isn't actually doing anything since the `Context` you're attempting to cast is your `Activity`, not your `AnimationFragment`.

Instead of reaching up to get your listener, your `AnimationFragment` should set the listener on the Dialog by overriding `onAttachFragment()`.

First, you need to make sure that your `MonDialogFragment` is a child fragment of your `AnimationFragment` by changing your `show()` to use `getChildFragmentManager()`:

```
myDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
```

Then, override `onAttachFragment()` in your `AnimationFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

    if (fragment instanceof MonDialogFragment) {
        ((MonDialogFragment) fragment).listener = this;
    }
}
```

You can then remove `onAttach()` from `MonDialogFragment` entirely.

Comment: I have try your code has it was pretty logic to me that your answer was the solution. But it still have the same error. Android studio was showing error in one line so I add ((MonDialogFragment) fragment).listener = (MonDialogListener).this;

Comment: Is your `onAttachFragment()` actually setting a listener? What do you mean by 'Android studio was showing error in one line'? You can update your question.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the onAttachFragment has to be on the Animation Fragment not on the Dialog... your answer is good and I really thank you. I'll try to understand why to explain it well to to my student in my introduction to computer science course. Upvote and great thank

Comment: Yeah, it is the parent that is handling the child being attached, so `onAttachFragment()` goes on the parent. Best of luck going forward!